# 401 status in get request

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-boot

hello everybody i'm working in (spring/angular) application and when i send a GET request for authentification , i get this error :
i'm using angular 5 for front-end and spring boot 2/mysql for back-end

[image]

This my spring security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS= {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/book/**",
            "/user/**",
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable().
        httpBasic().and().
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

this is my Filter :

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter{


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req ,ServletResponse res,FilterChain chain) {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;


        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methodes","POST,PUT,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","x-requested-with,x-auth-token");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age","3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");


            if(!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")){
                try {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("preflight");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methodes","POST,GET,DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age","3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","authorization,content-type,x-auth-token,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,x-requested-with");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }


}
```

this my controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/token")
    public Map<String, String> token(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request){

        String remoteHost=request.getRemoteHost();
        int portNumber=request.getRemotePort();
        System.out.println(remoteHost +":"+portNumber);
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());        
        return Collections.singletonMap("token",session.getId());
    }
```

this is my angular 5 service :

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic " + encodedCredentials;
    let headers=new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': basicHeader
      });

    return this.http.get(url,{headers:headers});

  }
}
```

Comment: `401` means unauthorized request, for the request `http://localhost:8080/token` also backend people expecting the jwt token, which is the wrong from backend side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please allow OPTIONS requests from your security config class as client (angular) first send OPTIONS request to verify server allow to custom added headers then send actual request to server.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
```

**Note:** Please note as you are using `Bcrypt` password but `Basic Http` will send `Base64` encoded password so this might be issue so check logic in `UserSecurityService`.

Comment: the same problem !  pic : http://www3.0zz0.com/2018/09/27/00/993444344.png , i think there in not problem with option it work : pic http://www11.0zz0.com/2018/09/27/00/148758892.png

Comment: hmm seems your filter is passing options request..if(!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")),I am little confuse one side you are using Bcrypt encryption for password and other side you are trying to use basic auth which is base 64 encoded.Can you add code of UserSecurityService.

Comment: thank you the problem was in UserSecurityService in Bcrpt encryption .